# How do I set up multiple displays for a single computer over ethernet

Tags: networking

Currently I have 4 computers in separate rooms, connected through ethernet. It is a dental clinic and those computers are used to plug in some equipment via usb.

I was wondering if it would be possible to have just one computer, and multiple displays, with usb connectors. That would solve many of the issues we are having with synchronization of the data between computers.

I simply want to have one computer have multiple displays and be able to connect usb at each display location. Ethernet connection is available.

It is okay if they all display the same view.

Comment: It sounds like you're solving the wrong problem. If there's a problem with synching the data across the 4 computers then why not centralize the data?

Comment: @joeqwerty We have a pc that acts as a server. It runs an application that we use for managing patients information. We connected to that application at each one of the client PC. We also have several Window's Shared folders. Our information is all in one place. The folder that we share holds about 14GB of images, stored in folders – each for a client. It gets really slow to open it. The application managing the patient information is also having issues, it hangs all the time and it is slow as hell. It is very fast when I use it from the server

Comment: So I wanted to see if we could just have multiple monitors, and one computer.

Comment: Ok then you should just buy 4 thin clients for your server. http://www.usb-over-network.com/usbnet-solutions/thinclients.html

Comment: Which OS is it?

Comment: Keeping the data on just one computer might not solve the problem, but rather hide it. Instead of having copies get out of sync, you might just end up having users overwrite each other's changes.

Comment: @KonradGajewski Windows.

Comment: @IjazKhan That's looks useful and may be part of the solution, but I would still need a way to use an application that is running on the server computer from the client computer. So I need a way to use (keyboard, mouse, display) the server computer from the client one.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, and I would solve it by getting terminals for windows.